# Selecting COUNT values for multiple joined tables separately

Tags: sql, join

We have an online course platform, where the data model is oriented around chapter, chapter_views and discussions.

## Desired result:

I am trying to select these stats data and produce single table with the most popular/viewed chapters. The result should look similar to this:

```
chapter title | views count | discussions count |
=================================================
Chapter 01    | 258         | 12                |
-------------------------------------------------
Chapter 02    | 1254        | 985               |
-------------------------------------------------
Chapter 03    | 11          | 1                 |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I can get views count easilly and fast by counting joined `ahoy_events` as `views` table. The problem is that I need to get discussions count per chapter as well. When I am trying to add `discussions_count` to the query as 'nested' select, it just takes too long to process.

## Existing data structure

### Chapters

```
column      | type
===================
id          | uuid
section_id  | uuid
title       | character varying
created_at  | timestamp
updated_at  | timestamp
```

### Sections

```
column      | type
===================
id          | uuid
course_id   | uuid
title       | character varying
created_at  | timestamp
updated_at  | timestamp
```

### Courses

```
column      | type
===================
id          | uuid
teacher_id  | uuid
title       | character varying
created_at  | timestamp
updated_at  | timestamp
```

### Discussions

```
column      | type
===================
id          | uuid
chapter_id  | uuid
title       | character varying
body        | text
created_at  | timestamp
updated_at  | timestamp
```

### Ahoy::Events - upon every chapter visit one row is created

```
column      | type
===================
id          | uuid
user_id     | uuid
name        | character varying (defaults to "student.chapter.show"
properties  | jsonb (for chapter views: {chapter_id: '2sdfl1h123-12hh12'}
created_at  | timestamp
updated_at  | timestamp
```

Since its an Rails app, we used Ahoy gem to track multiple user events and actions. This is just one of them. The structure of `ahoy_events` table is therefore set in stone and we use the gem's rules to save data - that's why we use jsonb column to save data for this particular event type (chapter view).

## My take on this problem

I have come up with this query:

```
SELECT
  chapters.id,
  chapters.title,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(views.id) AS views_count
    FROM chapters ch1
    LEFT JOIN ahoy_events views ON (views.properties->>'chapter_id' = ch1.id::text)
    WHERE ch1.id = chapters.id
      AND views.time >= '2021-05-01 00:00:00 +0200'
      AND views.time <= '2021-05-31 00:00:00 +0200'
  ), (
    SELECT COUNT(discussions.id) AS discussions_count
    FROM chapters ch2
    LEFT JOIN discussions ON (discussions.chapter_id = ch2.id)
    WHERE ch2.id = chapters.id
      AND discussions.created_at >= '2021-05-01 00:00:00 +0200'
      AND discussions.created_at <= '2021-05-31 00:00:00 +0200'
  )
FROM chapters
LEFT JOIN sections ON (sections.id = chapters.section_id)
WHERE sections.course_id = '7015d82d-863a-47b2-88a2-0120b13472be'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY views_count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

which works, but it takes 90 seconds to process (ahoy_events table consists of about 10M rows).

Can you guys help me to find out less complex and more efficient way to do this. Or do I have to split this into two separate queries?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the data.  The query and question are unrelated.  Why does Chapter 02 appear twice in the results?  I assume that is a typo.

Comment: without knowing your actual table structure no one can decide query. Please share table and sample data scripts

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: I have updated the description with more details about the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should shared CREATE TABLE statements and some example data (INSERT statements) so We can test the query.

It seems your RDBMS is Postgresql, but I am not sure.

I changed a bit your query, try it an let me know if execution time was improve (We can test different versions of the query).

To improve execution time you should define indexes (you should examine the execution plan).

```
SELECT
  chapters.id,
  chapters.title,
  sqv.views_count, 
  sqd.discussions_count
  
FROM chapters
INNER JOIN sections ON sections.id = chapters.section_id

LEFT JOIN (SELECT views.properties->>'chapter_id' AS chapter_id, COUNT(views.id) AS views_count
           FROM ahoy_events views
           WHERE views.created_at >= '2021-05-01 00:00:00 +0200' AND views.created_at <= '2021-05-31 00:00:00 +0200'
           GROUP BY views.properties->>'chapter_id') sqv ON sqv.chapter_id = chapters.id::text

LEFT JOIN (SELECT d.chapter_id, COUNT(d.id) AS discussions_count
           FROM discussions d
           WHERE d.created_at >= '2021-05-01 00:00:00 +0200' AND d.created_at <= '2021-05-31 00:00:00 +0200'
           GROUP BY d.chapter_id) sqd ON sqd.chapter_id = chapters.id

WHERE sections.course_id = '7015d82d-863a-47b2-88a2-0120b13472be'
ORDER BY sqv.views_count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

You could create an index on ahoy_events.created_at and other on discussions.created_at to speed up search (keep in mind that indexes use up space and slow down data modification).